# Solr How to add boost factor to double field value

Tags: solr, lucene

My ecommerce website is using solr to index the products for customer search. There is a solr field called "sale_revenue_double" described the total revenue of product.

My purpose is, when customer performs the search text, I want the products with higher sale revenues easily appeared in the tops of result. I didn't expected that is a solr sort by this field, because when using the solr sort for "sale_revenue_double", the search result is mostly displayed by this sort order, not the expectation for the text search. So I just want, look like to add a small boost factor to "sale_revenue_double" (or any similar thing) to lift up a little bit the products with high sale revenue, not change to much the result by other factors.

However when I added boost factor for this field, it needs to be specified the value, such as  bq=(sale_revenue_double:200000^10.0), but with my case, the value (200000) doesn't make sense, because we don't need to specify the specific revenue, we just care the high revenue in the result will be lift a little bit.
So i'm getting trouble with it and don't have solution with this requirement.

Experts if anyone have any ideas to resolve this issue, please help me.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [the `bf` parameter](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_4/the-dismax-query-parser.html#bf-boost-functions-parameter) or [the `boost` parameter](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_4/the-extended-dismax-query-parser.html#extended-dismax-parameters) (additive vs multiplicative boosting) with a function to get the boost profile you're looking for based on the value in the field.

`bf=sqrt(sale_revenue_double)` will give you a boost that corresponds to the square root of the sale (which will make it grow a lot slower). Exactly what profile you want to use will depend on how much you want the score to be affected, and how different these revenue figures are.